# Angular skipping over a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 controllers on my angular module.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
    function($scope, $http, $timeout) { .... }];

app.controller('FooterCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {  ....  }];
```

The first one works fine but the second is just not being processed at all. Even the `console.log()` inside its function does not work.

They have been registered the same way. Really strange that one works but the other is just skipped over.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1e8XQl1y5t3bAImP6tnu?p=preview) here.

**Note**: The `FooterCtrl` controller is used in `footer-cell.html` not in `index.html`

**Edit**: Looks like the problem lies with the `inspector-gadget` module I'm using. Using the `FooterCtrl` in its top element works fine but putting it in the `<inspector-title>` or `<inspector-content>` causes the this problem. Weird because their [documentation](http://softwaredoug.github.io/inspector-gadget/#/home) shows its to be used with 
`<inspector-content>`.

Comment: I cannot see your html. is the footer loaded? do you see any error in the console?

Comment: No errors on the console. The footer is loaded but the `console.log` inside the `FooterCtrl` function is not seen on the console. A breakpoint on the `console.log` line is never reached :(

Comment: Doing a hover on your footer element shows that angular isn't even processing that html. You might need to wrap something in a `$compile` or something.

Comment: Something like that is my guess too. Still trying to figure out what exactly needs to be done.